# Deep Linking Working Fine in Android, It's Navigating to Different App Screen. But In IOS It's Opening the App via link but Not Navigating

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am implementing Deep Linking in flutter. In Android, it's working perfectly fine, It's Navigating to Different App Screen via this method(_initHandleDeepLinks()). But in IOS it's opening the app via link but not navigating to different app screen. initialLink is coming null I guess, any solutions?

## handleDeepLink code

```
Future<void> _initHandleDeepLinks() async {
final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
print("link1" + initialLink.toString());

if (initialLink != null) {
  final Uri? deepLink = initialLink.link;

  if (deepLink!.path == '/doctors/karachi') {
    try {
      Get.toNamed(RouteConstants.instantConsultationIntroRoute12);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you follow all steps in [Firebase doc on dynamic links for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive#apple_platforms) ? where very important steps are to add the link to `applinks` and add `FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains` if you're using cusome domain in `Info.plist`

Comment: yes, I followed all steps, I will recheck it again. btw I am checking deep linking in release mode, do I have to check on test flight? maybe there are some permission issues in release mode.

Comment: If u config it correctly it should work on all modes, not just release. One thing are u using custom domain or links provided by firebase(have link and page parts)

Comment: am using the dynamic links provided by firebase dynamic short links.

Answer (score 1):

issue resolved.the missing thing was firebase ios sdk. you can add dependencies from xcode->project runner-> add dependencies and then search for "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk" and add package.

Comment: Did you add all the packages or just FirebaseDynamicLinks? And do you have your universal link paths defined on Info.plist? I'm using GoRouter and having the same problem. Links work just fine when app is on background but it does not work when app is cold starting only on iOS